# Why is SIGINT propagated to child processes but not SIGTERM?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, signals

I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool` to spawn 2 child processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time


def job(job_id: int):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"{pid} started {job_id}")
    while True:
        print(f"{pid} sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)


def main() -> None:
    pool = Pool(2)
    for job_id in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(job, [job_id])

    pid = os.getpid()
    while True:
        print(f"Main process with pid {pid} sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running the above code outputs:

```
Main process with pid 27769 sleeping
27770 started 0
27770 sleeping
27771 started 1
27771 sleeping
Main process with pid 27769 sleeping
27770 sleeping
27771 sleeping
```

If I send SIGINT to the main process `kill -s SIGINT 27769`, the entire operation is stopped (which is what I want) and the following error message shows up:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leonarduschen/src/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/leonarduschen/src/main.py", line 22, in main
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

However, if I send SIGTERM to the main process `kill -s SIGTERM 27769`, only the main process is killed. The message `terminated` is printed and my terminal is freed, but the child processes are still running and printing:

```
27770 sleeping
27771 sleeping
Main process with pid 27769 sleeping
Terminated
(venv) :~/src/$ 27770 sleeping
27771 sleeping
```

I cannot find any information about this in `multiprocessing` documentation. Why are the 2 signals handled differently?

Comment: Also if it matters, I'm on Linux

Comment: Signals do not propagate from parent to child. SIGINT is caught by python but SIGTERM is not.